# How to get the current number of in-use bean instances (MDB) from Wildfly?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, message-driven-bean

I have multiple MDB (message-driven-beans) in Wildfly that I want to monitor, and I'm looking for a way to get the current number of in-use bean instances for each MDB.

I'm currently getting MDB data/stats from Wildfly with the follwing `--command`:

```
/deployment=my-ear.ear/subdeployment=com.test.my-ejb.jar/subsystem=ejb3/message-driven-bean=*/:read-resource(include-runtime=true)" --output-json
```

Returning approx. *(Only showing result for one MDB)*:

```
{
  "outcome": "success",
  "result": [
    {
      "address": [
        {
          "deployment": "my-ear.ear"
        },
        {
          "subdeployment": "com.test.my-ejb.jar"
        },
        {
          "subsystem": "ejb3"
        },
        {
          "message-driven-bean": "MyMDB"
        }
      ],
      "outcome": "success",
      "result": {
        "activation-config": [
          {
            "destinationLookup": "my_queue"
          },
          {
            "acknowledgeMode": "Auto-acknowledge"
          },
          {
            "destinationType": "jakarta.jms.Queue"
          },
          {
            "maxSession": "3"
          }
        ],
        "component-class-name": "no.test.MyMDB",
        "declared-roles": [],
        "delivery-active": true,
        "execution-time": 0,
        "invocations": 0,
        "message-destination-link": null,
        "message-destination-type": null,
        "messaging-type": "jakarta.jms.MessageListener",
        "methods": {},
        "peak-concurrent-invocations": 0,
        "pool-available-count": 5,
        "pool-create-count": 0,
        "pool-current-size": 0,
        "pool-max-size": 5,
        "pool-name": "my-pool",
        "pool-remove-count": 0,
        "run-as-role": null,
        "security-domain": "other",
        "timeout-method": null,
        "timers": [],
        "transaction-type": "CONTAINER",
        "wait-time": 0,
        "service": null
      },
      "rolled-back": null
    }
  ]
}
```

But there is no information about the current number of in-use bean instances.

There is the attribute `pool-current-size` but this attribute seems to include idle bean instances.

Is there a way to get the number of in-use bean instances from Wildfly, or a way to extrapolate the number by using other attributes? Maybe is the way to use the `pool-current-size` but reduce idle time for bean instances?

Comment: Yeah I don't think there is a metric for this. The question I would ask is why you want to know this value. It's highly volatile unless your mdb takes a long time to handle a message.  If you need to the the second, you can't use tricks like entering values into a in-memory store and remove in your mdb finally.

Comment: Rather than looking at the actual in use count, knowing the current pool size Vs max and/or the number of messages on your queue is often more useful

Comment: @WillTatam Seems like an interesting metric. We have a pool-size of 100, and ~10 MDB's with a maxSession of 80. Takes approx. 1sec to handle a message, and receive maybe 300,000 messages a day for this pool.